# how to git merge other files(except specific folder) and specific files in specific folder

Tags: git

For example,I have a project branch master like this:

```
project_folder
|
|---a.txt
|---b.txt
|---c.txt
|---folder1
    |---sub_a.txt
    |---sub_b.txt
    |---sub_c.txt
```

and branch a like this

```
project_folder
|
|---a.txt
|---b.txt
|---c.txt
|---folder1
    |---sub_a.txt
```

and branch b like this

```
project_folder
|
|---a.txt
|---b.txt
|---c.txt
|---folder1
    |---sub_b.txt
```

...

l want to merge master and a with all file, except sub_b.txt, sub_c.txt. And the same with merging master and b

PS: it will add new file like `xxx.txt` into `folder1`

Comment: Your perspective is off base. A file is not a particularly meaningful unit in git's history. The basic unit is a commit. If you want to merge only some changes, they should be in separate commits.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot ignore a file, when doing merge. You can do merge with --no-commit option to inspect the changes after the merge, instead of autocommit.

```
git checkout a
git merge --no-commit master
git rm folder/sub_b.txt #to not consider this file for commit
git rm folder/sub_c.txt #to not consider this file for commit
git commit -m "merge of master to branch a"
```

repeat the same for branch b also.

```
git checkout b
git merge --no-commit master
git rm folder/sub_b.txt #to not consider this file for commit
git rm folder/sub_c.txt #to not consider this file for commit
git commit -m "merge of master to branch b"
```